# ¿Como puedo relizar este codigo para devolver true o false? Si me lo pueden decir rapido lo agradeceria mucho

Tags: c++

Necesito que me tire e imprima True si es mayor a 18 y false si es menor.

```
case 2: cout<<"Usted selecciono la opcion 2 \n";
    
    
    printf("Ingrese su edad: \n");
    scanf("%i",edad);

    
        
    if(edad >= 18 && edad <121){
        scanf("%i",edad);   
        return true;
    }
    
    if(edad >0 && edad <18){
        return false;
    }
    
    
    break;
```

Comment: hay un scanf que te sobra (si ya has pedido la edad y esta entre los valores aceptados, con devolver true es suficiente). Tampoco te hace falta el segundo if (seria un else del anterior)

Answer (score 0):

> Necesito que me tire e imprima True si es mayor a 18 y false si es menor.

```
std::cout << (edad > 18 ? "True" : "false");
```